# Toggling class display rule every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a relatively simple demo here where I have two embed elements with the same class, and upon page load one is set to display and the other is not. I'm calling a function and setting an interval for every 5 seconds starting on page load which should toggle the display rules for the classes  (only one embed element should show at a time and then they should alternate on the timer).

I have border colors on the embed elements for testing, but it seems like neither element is showing on page load once I added the second 'if' statement in the JS

What am I doing wrong

```js
window.onload = function () {
    test();
    setInterval(function() {
        test();
    }, 5000);
}


function test(){
    console.log('starting');
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('pdfEmbed');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {    
        if(all[i].style.display = "none"){
            all[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        if(all[i].style.display="block"){
            all[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<embed class="pdfEmbed" src="#" style="margin-top: 40px;position:absolute; display: block; left: 0; top: 0; border: 1px solid red;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">

    <embed class="pdfEmbed" src="#" style="margin-top: 40px;position:absolute; border: 1px solid black; display: none; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: why don't you use a css animation that loops indefinately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening with the second `if`:

```
// set current child display to "block" if it is "none"
if(all[i].style.display = "none"){
    all[i].style.display = "block";
}
// the check is always true, since you just set the display to "block"
if(all[i].style.display="block"){
    // therefore, for all elements set display to none
    all[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

The fix is easy: Use an `else if` instead of the second `if`. In case you only want to have the two display states "none" and "block", an `else` is enough.

EDIT: I just noticed a second error. You have to use comparison (`==` or `===`) instead of assignment (`=`) in your `if` conditions. So this should be working:

```
if(all[i].style.display == "none") {
  all[i].style.display = "block";
} else {
  all[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I definiltey overlooked the comparison issue so that's why my original if/else wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var last_index = 0;

function test() {

    var e = document.querySelectorAll(".pdfEmbed");

    for (var k = 0; k < e.length; k++) {
        e[k].style.display = k == last_index ? "block" : "none";
    }
    last_index++;

    if (last_index >= e.length) { last_index = 0; }

}
```